# Django admin limiting some foreign keys value, example limiting pin values to only pins that have no items attached

Tags: django, admin

Board class will have a name, port etc, Pin has as an attribute the Board foreign key, that is a pin is attached to a board. An item is attached to a pin which is connected on the board. So I need to retrieve all pins that have not been used yet by other items so as when I add a new item in the admin panel, it gives as foreign key only pin-boards that have not been attached yet.

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique="True")

class Pin(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField()
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)

#Item will be have as foreign key pin and board
class Item(models.Model):
    Item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pin = models.ForeignKey(Pin,unique="True")`
```

Comment: It depends where you'll use it what you want to do with this code but something like `Pin.objects.annotate(item_count=Count('item')).filter(item_count__gt=0)` should get the queryset you're after. You can try this in the Django shell.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist thanks replying. In fact, i am using this in the admin panel when adding a new item. When a pin will be selected, i want only the pins that have not been used based on this query. in my case(as tested on shell) it will be:Pin.objects.annotate(item_count=Count('item')).filter(item_count__=0) But actually i can't apply it in the admin panel :/ please help